# lower limit of the Cumulative distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am having some trouble with understanding the following:
I have a probability density function $f_X=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ when $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

I want to find the CDF by integrating, so the integral of that would be $-1\over1+x$, but I am getting confused with the limits. I know I am meant to integrate from $-\infty$ up to $x$.

Now since everything below $x=0$ is $0$ I can just integrate from $0$ to $x$.
if instead $f_X=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ when $x\geq0$ then I would get 1-1/(1+x) but since at $x=0$, $f_X=0$. I am getting confused as that would give me just $-\frac{1}{1+x}$ which is negative.. I might be wrong.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You need the cumulative distribution to be $0$ when $x=0$, since the probability of $x<0$ is $0$.

Comment: yes so the CDF is 0 for x<=0 but what value should I get for x>0?a as I do not know what to use for my lower limit because -1/(1+x) tends to 0 as x tends to minus infinity so then I get a negative answer but probabilities have to be positive..

Comment: CDF for $x\ge 0$ (or $x>0$) is $\int_0^x \frac1{(1+t)^2}\,dt$. Perhaps you have used $x$ for both the integrand and limit of integration.

Comment: Basically you integrate the expression for the density over $(-\infty,x] \cap [0,\infty)$, which is $[0,x]$ if $x \geq 0$ and $\emptyset$ otherwise. What's a bit confusing is that we have notation for integrating over "$[0,x]$" when $x<0$, i.e. $\int_0^x f(t) dt$, but this isn't what is actually happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cumulative distribution is 0 for $x<0$.  Your expression is only valid for positive $x$.

The cumulative distribution for non-negative $x$ will be 
$$F(x)=\frac{-1}{1+x}+C$$
but since $F(0)=0$, then
$$0 = \frac{-1}{1+0}+C$$
So $C=1$, and the cumulative distribution is given by $1-\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Comment: That's really clear now, thank you!!